# Why isn't react-bootstrap table not working

Tags: reactjs, html-table, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

i wanted to create a table using react-bootstrap .so installed react-bootstrap by
`npm install react-bootstrap boostrap`
then i imported the `Table` from `react-bootstrap` and rendered the table but it is not styled?

why isn't this working ?

```
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap'
```

```
<Table striped bordered hover>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Chest No.</th>
    </tr>        
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>No one</td>
      <td>101</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</Table>
```

this table in not styled (no hover, no strip ........)

Comment: Do other components work? Did you import `bootstrap.css`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to import **bootstrap**.
Add the following line inside your **index.js** file

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/twilight-frost-115jrn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported the bootstrap CSS file?
If not, you could import it in your **index.js** file.

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

or

Download **bootstrap.min.css**.
Then import it

```js
import 'path-to-bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css';
```